# Функция не возвращает модифицированный список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо модифицировать список. Элементы списка, которые четные числа, должны быть поделены на 2, к нечетным числам из списка прибавляем один. Необходимо вывести модифицированный список не пользуясь `print`.

Вот моя реализация:

```
def modify_list(lst):
    res = []
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        y=int(lst[i])
        if y%2==0:
            res.append(int(y/2))
        else:
            res.append(y+1)
    return res

modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Смотрела через визуализатор, заполнение списка идет, но вывода модифицированного списка нет. В чем проблема?

Comment: Никаких проблем нет, функция возвращает модифицированный список. Вопрос лишь в том, что его надо все-таки выводить на печать. Если не через `print(modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6]))`, то как-то иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1:

```
In [9]: import sys

In [10]: _ = [sys.stdout.write(f"{x}\n") for x in modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6])]
2
1
4
2
6
3
```

Вариант 2: без импорта модулей:

```
In [14]: with open(1, "w") as f:
    ...:     for x in modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6]):
    ...:         f.write(f"{x}\n")
    ...:
2
1
4
2
6
3
```

PS `1` - соответствует `STDOUT`

---

Если выводить надо в виде списка:

```
In [18]: sys.stdout.write(str(modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6])))
[2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3]
```

или:

```
In [17]: with open(1, "w") as f:
    ...:     f.write(str(modify_list([1,2,3,4,5,6])))
    ...:
[2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3]
```